# php array for default value

Tags: php, arrays

```
$timetable = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
    $timetable[$i.':00'] = $i.':00';
    $timetable[$i.':15'] = $i.':15';
    $timetable[$i.':30'] = $i.':30';
    $timetable[$i.':45'] = $i.':45';
}

$fields["ready"] = array("label" => "Opbouwklaar", "type" => "select", "options" => $timetable);
```

How can you set a default value to the following array?
I have already tried set a "blank" or "default" in the array but this didn't work unfortunately.

Now the default value is standard 0:00, this is because that is the first option in the for statement.

Comment: What do you mean by default value of the array ? I think you are displaying those hours in a select and it's in this select that you wan't to display a default value, right ?

Comment: if default value is not dynamic, you can directly declare before `$timetable` loop and include it in `$fields['ready']`

Comment: What about add to `$fields["ready"]` array another index called "selected" and value to check and mark as selected ??

Answer (score 1):

You can not set a default value for an array in a selectbox. If there is no 'selected' value then the 1st selection will show.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really clear. So I made some assumptions.

I guess you want a specific value in the select-element being selected when the page is loaded?

With this example down below you set the 'selected' (default?) value in the `if()` statement. In this example, value '10:15' is selected by default.

```
<?php

$timetable = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
    $timetable[$i.':00'] = $i.':00';
    $timetable[$i.':15'] = $i.':15';
    $timetable[$i.':30'] = $i.':30';
    $timetable[$i.':45'] = $i.':45';
}

$fields["ready"] = array("label" => "Opbouwklaar", "type" => "select", "options" => $timetable);

?>

<select>
    <?php foreach($fields['ready']['options'] as $option){
        if ($option = "10:15"){ $selected = "selected";}
        echo "<option $selected value='$option'>$option</option>";
    }?>
</select>
```